# How could I use postcss-bem with css-modules or postcss-js in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, postcss, css-modules

I am learning how to use postcss-bem to generate css files in bem style,
but I wonder if there're some package like the CSS-Modules or Postcss-JS, that I could use to doing something like below:

```js
const ReactComp extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let styles = './postcss-bem.css'
    return <div class={styles.blockname}>something</div>
  }
}
```

I found this feature on the documents of CSS-Modules and Postcss-JS
but when I try to use webpack's postcss-loader with postcss-JS to parser the postcss-bem.css

> loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader","postcss-loader?parser=postcss-js"]

But I got the error like this

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postcss-js is a CSS-in-JS solution, so it works with CSS written in JS.

According file extention, you use CSS, not JS in postcss-bem.css.

Also there is no any sense to use postcss-bem plugin with CSS Modules. BEM allow you to isolate CSS by having prefix for every selector. But CSS Modules isolate CSS too. So you this two PostCSS tools do same thing.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood the propose of postcss-js,
and have found the solution for loading the css token into js file now,

I modify my webpack.config.js,  
use css-loader to hash and loading the css token into my React component as classNames.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrey,
Here's my solution : using the css-loader to hash and load css token into js file.

```js
//add these code into webpack.config.js
module: {
 loaders: [
  {
  test:   /\.css$/,
  loaders: [
   'style-loader',
   'css-loader?' + 'modules&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]',
   'postcss-loader'
      ],
  }
 ]
},
```

and in the JSX file, we can use import to load css token

```js
export default class Comp1 extends Component{
    render () {
     const css = require( './style.css');
        return <div className={css['Comp_name']}><Comp11 /></div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case you doesn’t need a postcss-bem and postcss-js.